# FluentValidation passing parameter

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

I've found FluentValidation only couple of hours ago and I want to rewrite all my validation logic so it will use only FV.

The issue that I have ATM is that I would like to use data coming from input as a parameter for DomainExists() method. Is it possible or do I have to figure out a way around FV to achieve that?

```
    public QuoteValidator()
    {
    // hardcoded because don't know how to pass input string to RuleFor
        var inputeddomain = "http://google.com";

        RuleFor(r => r.Domain).NotEqual(DomainExists(inputeddomain));
    }

    // checks if inputeddomain is in repository (SQL DB)
    private string DomainExists(string inputeddomain)
    {
        var context = new QuoteDBContext().Quotes;
        var output = (from v in context
                     where v.Domain == inputeddomain
                     select v.Domain).FirstOrDefault();

        if (output != null) { return output; } else { return "Not found"; }
    }
```

Thanks to @bpruitt-goddard hint I got that to work. Here's a solution to my problem (hope it will help somebody).

```
        public QuoteValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(r => r.Domain).Must(DomainExists).WithMessage("{PropertyValue} exists in system!");
    }

    private bool DomainExists(string propertyname)
    {
        var context = new QuoteDBContext().Quotes;
        var output = (from v in context
                      where v.Domain == propertyname
                      select v.Domain).FirstOrDefault();

        if (output != null) { return false; } else { return true; }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use FluentValidation's `Must` method to pass in extra data from the input object.

```
RuleFor(r => r.Domain)
  .Must((obj, domain) => DomainExists(obj.InputDomain))
  .WithErrorCode("MustExist")
  .WithMessage("InputDomain must exist");
```

Although this will work, it is not recommended to check for database existence in the validation layer as this is **verification** versus **validation**. Instead, this kind of check should be done in the business layer.